# .NET Web Scripting

Tags: http, scripting, client

I'm attempting to right a script to logon (username and password) on to a website and download a file. I've tried using the webClient and webBrowser classes to no avail, they don't seem to work for what I need them to do.

Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: Too vague. Do you need to use HTTP protocol authentication or submit a HTML form? Explain how you tried to use webClient/webBrowser and how they failed.

Comment: I used them to connect to a site and submit the form via a click event. The problem is using them to maintain the state. Once a button or link is clicked, the instance does not "move" to the next page. And I would like the instance to interact with the website. It needs to log in, follow the page forwarding and then download a file via a link button.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look at [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471062/c-webclient-view-source-question/1521292#1521292). This is not specific to any programming language or platform (you didn't mention which language/platform you're using, so I can't offer any specific code advice) but in my answer I detail the basic approach you'll need to take for successful HTML [screen-scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping#Screen_scraping).

In a nutshell, first you'll need to the right combination of HTTP headers, URLs, and POST data to fool the server into thinking your client app is a "real" browser. A tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) which allows you to see actual HTTP requests going over the wire, and experimentally build new requests based on browser requests, is invaluable here.

Next you'll need to figure out, in your language and platform, how to produce that set of headers, URLs, and/or POST data.  Typically, handling cookies and redirects are the hardest-- and most platforms have specialized classes (e.g. [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) in .NET) to help with things like this.