# Get HTML in C# from page that Loads Dynamic Data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get data from a website an C#:

```
https://secure.lni.wa.gov/verify/Detail.aspx?LIC=1CALLCC871KC
```

It looks like this website gets the data from an ajax call after the page loads.  When I call this code:

```
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        return client.DownloadString(URL);
    }
```

It gets the base HTML but does not process the ajax call and fill in the data.  Is there a way to get the final page after rendering from code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get html that is generated via AJAX in webclient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950821/get-html-that-is-generated-via-ajax-in-webclient)

Comment: are you using the url of the website or the url accessed by the ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parsing that html content you can directly call the *GetBusinessDetails* method to get a json result back.

```
string URL = "https://secure.lni.wa.gov/verify/Controller.aspx/GetBusinessDetails";

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    var json =  client.UploadString(URL, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { License = "1CALLCC871KC", Ubi ="", IrlVilationId="", IsSecured="" }));

    dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    Console.WriteLine(response.d.ReturnValue.Contractor.BusinessName.ToString());
}
```

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` are methods in [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library