# output to a web site from winforms app

Tags: vb.net, winforms, processstartinfo

I have an winforms VB application that outputs a string of characters to a serial port and it goes through RS232 port to another computer and writes to a portal on the other computer -- I'm not sure if it writes one character at a time or the whole string. At any rate, there is a device between the 2 computers that emulates a keyboard input.

The character (or string or characters) is output wherever the cursor has focus on the other computer. I'm not sure whether I'm explaining this clearly, but the basic idea is to automate the typing of data into a web portal (it works very well).

However (to make a long story short), the goal is to eliminate the second computer, using extended dual screens. The application and the web portal would be open on the same computer (instead of 2) and output from the winforms application would be directed to the web portal and written where the focus is on the web portal.

The way that I imagine it should work is like this: a process would write text to a stream, but instead of redirecting the text to a file or the console, it would write it to wherever the cursor's focus is.

My question is what method could I use to do this? I've been looking into the ProcessStartInfo Class, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Would it not be possible to POST the data directly to the website instead of faking a user typing?

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140366/fill-form-c-sharp-post-error

Comment: Another alternative might be to use a browser control in the winforms app, and open the web portal in that. That way you could put text directly in the elements in the page, and don't need to emulate it in a different application.