# pass value to a web browser and print it in a particular textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a win-form application that generates passwords that I would like to send directly over to a web page textbox like input as apart of a new user sign up. I found a similair question. ([Fill Form C# & Post Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140366/fill-form-c-sharp-post-error)) But I dont think I am after the same goal. Is it possible to do this without using a macro or manually copy n pasting? The above post is in C# however I will ever using vb. If there is a answer on here please link, but I have gone through the forum.

Comment: Short answer: there is no simple solution. Long answer: yes, this is possible, but will require inordinate amounts of work and you'll have to manually target each browser via their automation systems.

Comment: How you'd do this is going to depend entirely on your web server and chosen server-side language. Most languages have a facility for executing external programs and piping output to a variable or stream (which can be output to a web page before being sent to the user. For example, PHP has the `Exec` command. If you're trying to send output to a page that has already been sent to the browser, this gets more complicated, and requires something like Ajax calls to retrieve the data after page load.

Comment: Thank you guys for your responses. It sounds like it would require more work than its worth. Guess I will stick with copy and paste or macros for now. Maybe after a couple more semesters I will understand this better, even then it sounds like it would be very complicated.